# Chainlink Keeper not performing upkeep

Tags: chainlink

I have a contract that is using Chainlink keepers for upkeep but the checkUpKeep/performUpkeep is not running. I have sufficiently funded the upkeep to ensure it has a high balance. The code from the contract was previously deployed, but now contains a minor change (outside the Chainlink functions), and the previous contract is receiving upkeeps. My code for checkUpKeep and performUpKeep are below:

```
function **checkUpkeep**(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
    if(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN){
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) >= duration;
    }
    else{
        upkeepNeeded = false;
    }
  }

function **performUpkeep**(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
    require(msg.sender == 0x4Cb093f226983713164A62138C3F718A5b595F73);
    lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.DRAWING;
    Random(random).getRandomNumber();
  }
```

As I mentioned earlier, this code is being used in another contract which is currently receiving upkeep so I am puzzled as to why it is not working in the new contract.

Comment: Does the working contract have this `require` statement, also? This is on Kovan testnet, right?

Comment: Yes, the working contract has the same `require` statement. It is the address of the keeper registry. And yes it is on the Kovan testnet.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a link to the registered upKeep associated with this contract?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: https://keepers.chain.link/kovan/1877

Comment: Unfortunately, I have trouble debugging it since your smart contract is not verified on Etherscan. You have successfully registered it for upkeep, it is funded, can be verified via Registry contract. Consider double-checking those minor changes since there is a solution for this problem. From the code snippet provided here, I can only tell that either `lottery state` is not open or `duration` is greater than `(block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp)`

Comment: I face the same issue. I check the link balance and the condition is just fine but It doesn't work. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your upkeeps are not being performed make sure to double-check the next items:

- Are Chainlink Keepers currently available on the network you are deploying to?
- Is your smart contract `KeeperCompatible`?
- Call `checkUpkeep`. Did it return `true` or `false`?
- Can you `performUpkeep`?
- Did you register your contract for upkeeps?
- Did you fund it?

Comment: I have done all of your suggestions listed except for calling `checkUpkeep` to see if it returns true or false and `performUpkeep`. I am unable to test the `performUpkeep' as the function can only be called by the keeper registry address for security reasons. However, I have difficulty testing `checkUpkeep` as the function requires a `bytes` parameter. Even though I commented it out it still requires it when called or it fails. And no matter what I try to pass as input to it it as `bytes` it does not accept it and still fails.